# Getting Java.lang.nullpointexcepton when I press back button from facebook login page in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my app, I am including login in my application with face book login. I am using 'OAuth' for social login. When user press face book login in login page, then we will navigate to the face book login page. Here is the problem is occur. After getting face book login page, When I press back button in my mobile getting fallowing exception. Can you please suggest what the cause of this issue. This type of exception is getting only in my xamarin android application.

Error :

[image]

sample code:

```cs
 var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator("ClientId", "email", new Uri("http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"), new Uri("http://appname/Account/LoginComplete"));

        auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    string emailAddress = string.Empty;

                    var token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                    var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                    var expireDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);
                    var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                    var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());
                    var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var name = obj["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var emailRequest = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + token + "xxx&fields=email"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                    var emailResponse = await emailRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                    var jsonString = JObject.Parse(emailResponse.GetResponseText());
                    string finalString = jsonString.ToString();

                    if (finalString.Contains("email"))
                    {
                        emailAddress = jsonString["email"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var emailRequest2 = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + token + "&fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email,timezone,age_range,verified"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                        var emailResponse2 = await emailRequest2.GetResponseAsync();
                        var jsonString2 = JObject.Parse(emailResponse2.GetResponseText());
                        finalString = jsonString2.ToString();
                        if(finalString.Contains("email"))
                            emailAddress = jsonString2["email"].ToString();

                    }

                    var password = string.Empty;

                    await LoadUser(emailAddress, password, name, token, id, expireDate);
                    //await FbUserContrloller.LoadFbUserDetails(emailAddress, password, name, token, id, expireDate);

                    AccountStore.Create(Context).Save(eventArgs.Account, App.AppName);

  activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
```

Comment: Update your question showing the code that is making your app to break, without this is really hard to know what is causing the crash.

Comment: Hi apindeda, Here is the code for face book login I am using.